# Spark: Transforming JSON files to correct format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I've 100+ million records stored in files with the following JSON structure (real data has way more columns, rows and is also nested)

```
{"id":"2-2-3","key":"value"}{"id":"2-2-3","key":"value"}{"id":"2-2-3","key":"value"}{"id":"2-2-3","key":"value"}{"id":"2-2-3","key":"value"}
```

The `sqlContext.read.json` function is unable to parse this since the records aren't on multiple lines but on one big line. The solution below solves this problem, but is a big performance killer. What would be the best way, performance wise, to handle this issue in Apache Spark?

```scala
val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("s3://some-bucket/**/*")
val validJSON = rdd.flatMap(_._2.replace("}{", "}\n{").split("\n"))

val df = sqlContext.read.json(validJSON)

df.count()
df.select("id").show()
```

Comment: What is the average size of the input file?

Comment: @user9613318 10mb, almost one million files in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a riff on [Antot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50067865/1188897), which should handle nested JSON

```
input.toVector
    .foldLeft((false, Vector.empty[Char], Vector.empty[String])) {
      case ((true, charAccum, strAccum), '{') => (false, Vector('{'), strAccum :+ charAccum.mkString);
      case ((_, charAccum, strAccum), '}')    => (true, charAccum :+ '}', strAccum);
      case ((_, charAccum, strAccum), char)   => (false, charAccum :+ char, strAccum)
    }
    ._3
```

Basically what it does is split the data into a `Vector[Char]`, and uses `foldLeft` to aggregate the input into substrings. The trick is to keep track of just enough information about the previous character to figure out if a `{` marks the start of a new object.

I used this input to test it (basically the OP's sample input, with a nested object thrown in):

```
val input = """{"id":"2-2-3","key":{ "test": "value"}}{"id":"2-2-3","key":"value"}{"id":"2-2-3","key":"value"}{"id":"2-2-3","key":"value"}{"id":"2-2-3","key":"value"}"""
```

And got this result, which looks good:

```
Vector({"id":"2-2-3","key":{ "test": "value"}}, 
       {"id":"2-2-3","key":"value"}, 
       {"id":"2-2-3","key":"value"}, 
       {"id":"2-2-3","key":"value"})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the original approach is the call `_._2.replace("}{", "}\n{"`, which creates another huge string from the input one, with new line chars inserted, which is then split once again into an array.

An improvement is possible by minimizing the creation of intermediate strings and retrieving the target ones as soon as possible. For this, we can play a bit with substrings:

```
val validJson = rdd.flatMap(rawJson => {

  // functions extracted to make it more readable.
  def nextObjectStartIndex(fromIndex: Int):Int = rawJson._2.indexOf('{', fromIndex)
  def currObjectEndIndex(fromIndex: Int): Int = rawJson._2.indexOf('}', fromIndex)
  def extractObject(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int): String = rawJson._2.substring(fromIndex, toIndex + 1)

  // the resulting strings are put in a local buffer
  val buffer = new ListBuffer[String]()

  // init the scanning of the input string
  var posStartNextObject = nextObjectStartIndex(0)

  // main loop terminates when there are no more '{' chars
  while (posStartNextObject != -1) {
    val posEndObject = currObjectEndIndex(posStartNextObject)
    val extractedObject = extractObject(posStartNextObject, posEndObject)
    posStartNextObject = nextObjectStartIndex(posEndObject)
    buffer += extractedObject
  }

  buffer
})
```

Please note that this approach would work only if the objects in the input JSON are not nested, supposing that all curly braces separate objects of same level.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer and interesting solution. Unfortunately this JSON is nested, I'll update my question.